# How to extract oldest date using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to figure out how to extract the oldest date among the list of file in specific folder,and then save it in a .txt file?

FOR EXAMPLE :

Each time you run the script I need to have the oldest  date only  in text file:
txt file shoud display - 20200726

Name

1. File_1_20200726
2. File_2_20200701

Thanks :-)

Comment: And where is your code ?

Comment: @simrandeepkuar Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share with us your coding attempt(s) to see how did you try to tackle to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any code, here is a powershell code, perhaps this can help you to make your own ?

```
$p = '\S+(\d{8})'
$MyString = @('File_1_20200726','File_2_20200701','File_2_20200781','File_0_20200725','File_hhsjj_ggee','Filewithoutdigits') | sort
$MyString | %{ [regex]::matches($_,$p) } | %{ $_.Groups[1].Value }
```

---

Output :

> ```
> 20200725
> 20200726
> 20200701
> 20200781
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit your date format to make this super easy using the `sort` or a `for` loop command in cmd.

I'm a bit torn but going with rhe slower for loop or rhe sort, since it seems you do or do not wa t the number before rhe date to factor in? And rhe file names may not be uniform.

I willtherefore assume you just want the oldest date and that it always comes after rhe 2nf underscore.

```
@( SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  SET "Folder=C:\Path\To\FilesFolder"
  SET "txtfile=C:\Path\For\DateFile.txt"
  SET "DIF=0"
  SET "CURRENT=10000000"
)

CALL :Main

( ENDLOCAL
  EXIT /B
)
  
:Main
  For /F "Tokens=3" %%_ IN ('
    DIR /B/A-D "%Folder%\*_*_*"
  ') DO (
    SET /A "DIF= _ - CURRENT"
    IF /I !DIF! LSS 0 SET /A "CURRENT= _"
  )
  Echo.%CURRENT%>>"%txtfile%"
  Echo.%CURRENT%
GOTO :EOF
```